# Why new entries are not inserted to database?

Tags: javascript, ipad, html, sqlite, safari

What I'm doing wrong? ExecuteSql is not throwing any errors, but new entries are actually not inserted into table.

```
// connection

var shortName = 'resultsDB';
        var version = '1.0';
        var displayName = 'QuizResultsDB';
        var maxSize = 655360;
        localDB = window.openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);

// tables are created succesfully

createTables: function(){

        localDB.transaction(function(tx){

            // add not null to email
            var query = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS results(User_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CompanyName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, EmailAddr VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, TimeCount INTEGER NOT NULL, ErrorsCount INTEGER NOT NULL)';
            tx.executeSql(query, [], function(tx, data){
                    }, function(tx, error){
                    //alert('Database table creation error' + error.message + '(' + error.code + ')');
                });
        });
    }, // -createTables
```

// trying to insert row

```
localDB.transaction(

                function(tx){

                    var query = 'INSERT INTO results(Name, CompanyName, EmailAddr, TimeCount, ErrorsCount) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';

                        tx.executeSql(query, [$.cookie('name'), $.cookie('companyName'), $.cookie('email'), parseInt($.cookie('timeNeeded')), parseInt($.cookie('errorsCount'))], function(tx, data){
                    // no error thrown

                        }, function(tx, error){
                        alert("Error saving results to local database " + error.message);
                    });
```

Comment: Did you tried to insert without passing parameters, like adding some static values in "query" variable and see if it got inserted or not? try to isolate the error ...

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to do a Commit to your transaction?

Comment: Doesn't executeSql do that? I'm new to html5 local database, so sorry if that seems to be a stupid question ;).

Comment: Don't worry, no questions are stupid :)Honestly I've never used it, I just would like to help cause I've seen this problem many times and it's always a commit missing problem. So it's just a hint. Don't forget to try mohammedn suggestion.